# My program is getting a false positive from AVG

Tags: vnc, antivirus, false-positive

My program is getting a false positive from AVG. Its just our companies branded version of Ultra VNC. Its only this one company that's identifying it as a virus and we've been using the same copy of that program for almost a year. I know its possible to tell this Anti Virus program the VNC client is safe, but I can't do that for all of our clients. I've tried to find a way to contact this company to see if they can do something to prevent this from happening, but I'm not getting anywhere. Has anyone who's experienced this issue with their software, found a solution?

Comment: Come on, what is this, kindergarten? Say the name of the program so there is no confusion. Is it AVG, KAV, what? The only way is probably to contact them and ask them to add an exception. Or you can use various packers in hopes that it will fool their detection engine.

Comment: I didn't say their name because I wasn't sure it was permitted here. Since its, in a small sense, a knock against that company. But yes its AVG.

Comment: @IVlad  if you say it three times do they appear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AVG [How To Handle Suspicious False Positive Detection](http://forums.avg.com/ww-en/avg-free-forum?sec=thread&act=show&id=395)

Comment: Thanks Martin, That post tells me who to send the file to. That's just what I was looking for but couldn't find. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I used old well-known virus approach of using `WinAPI` through `GetProcAddress` with function name obfuscation. Another approach is using (preferably non-standard) packers, cryptors and advanced copy-protection systems. If that doesn't help you will have to read more advanced virus manuals.